# Using str_replace within an already-existing function?

Tags: php, function, search, replace, str-replace

So right now, I have a simple function that I use to call some text content:

```
function htmlstuff() { ?>
<p>html text content here</p>
<? }
```

And on a page I call the text using:

```
<?php htmlstuff() ?>
```

Now, I need to figure out how to use "search and replace" for whatever text is in the function. I've tried things like

```
function str_replace($search,$replace,htmlstuff())
```

but I obviously don't know what the heck I'm doing. Is there any simple way to just search the text within the function and search/replace?

Comment: please elaborate on your questions abit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you really want to do?
if you want to search and replace and in the return variable of your htmlstuff function then
you are not too far away from the correct answer.

```
function htmlstuff() { 
 $htmlstuff = "<p>html text content here</p>";
 return $htmlstuff;
}

echo htmlstuff();

str_replace($search,$replace,htmlstuff());
```

this should do the trick

if you just want to make the function htmlstuff more dynamic, then you should take a different approach. something like this:

```
function htmlstuff($html) { 
 $htmlstuff = "<p>".$html."</p>";
 return $htmlstuff;
}

echo htmlstuff("html text content here");
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I guess if it were possible I'd like to keep the html outside of "echo" statements so I can edit the text raw with Dreamweaver's shortcuts etc., but it appears that the only way to accomplish the search/replace is to have the text within quotes of some sort. Thank you for your input, I'd vote this up but my rep is too low.

Comment: Done! haha i'm new to this sorry. Can you confirm if what I was saying is accurate? WOuld the text have to be in an echo or in quotes in order for the search/replace to be applied? Not sure if I'm making myself clear, it's jsut that when text/html is within quotes, Dreamweaver's shortcuts don't work.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem like this:

```
function htmlstuff ($content = "Default text goes here")
{
  echo "<p>" . $content . "</p>";
}
```

and then on another call you just `htmlstuff("New text to go there");`

And if I'm wrong correct me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$html_stuff = htmlstuff();
$search_for = "Hello, world!";
$replace_with = "Goodbye, world!";

$html_stuff = str_replace($search_for, $replace_with, $html_stuff);

echo $html_stuff;

function htmlstuff() { 
echo '<p>html text content here</p> ';
}
```

Comment: the function doesnt have a return value, $html_stuff = htmlstuff(); would be empty